# qt/c++ issue with inheritance and undeclared signal

Tags: c++, qt

I am messing around with qt and have created a custom label object that I am inheriting to another class. I have this issue where I am emitting a signal that is undeclared but I am not sure why since I declare the signal in the header file. The issue is in the subclass cpp file.

```
error: undeclared identifier 'Tile_Mouse_Action'
    emit Tile_Mouse_Action(QString("Clicked"), "test")
         ^
    dsf

compile output: ../Signals/tilewidget.cpp:13:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Tile_Mouse_Action'
    emit Tile_Mouse_Action(QString("Clicked"), "test")
         ^
../Signals/tilewidget.cpp:12:35: warning: unused parameter 'ev' [-Wunused-parameter]
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {
                                  ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [tilewidget.o] Error 1
10:16:32: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Signals (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.3 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Even if I try commenting out the emit line, I get other issues which leads me to believe there is something else wrong with my code. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for TileWidget", referenced from:
      TileWidget::TileWidget(QWidget*) in tilewidget.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Signals.app/Contents/MacOS/Signals] Error 1
10:26:28: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Signals (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.3 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

base class header file

```
class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);

    int x, y;
    char action[20];
    QString mouseAction;

signals:
    void Mouse_Pos();
    void Mouse_Press();
    void Mouse_DoubleClick();
    void Mouse_Action(QString, std::string);

public slots:
};
```

base class cpp file

```
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{

}

void MyLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {...

void MyLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {...

void MyLabel::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {...
```

subclass header file

```
class TileWidget : public MyLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TileWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);


signals:
    void Tile_Mouse_Action(QString, std::string); 

private slots:

};
```

subclass cpp file

```
TileWidget::TileWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    MyLabel(parent)
{

}

void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {
    emit Tile_Mouse_Action(QString("Clicked"), "test"); // issue here
};
```

Comment: You're missing the qualification `TileWidget::` in the definition of `mousePressEvent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to provide guidance without giving away the answer.

Try making sure your functions are in the same namespace. Look at your constructor and the mousePressEvent() function in your subclass. You'll need to tell the compiler they are part of the same class.

I run into this problem a lot when I write my own classes in Qt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I see I was missing TileWidget in my function declaration. However I am still getting this error: 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "TileWidget::Tile_Mouse_Action()", referenced from:
      TileWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*) in tilewidget.o
  "vtable for TileWidget", referenced from:
      TileWidget::TileWidget(QWidget*) in tilewidget.o

Comment: Try deleting the tilewidget.o file, or just clean, and then rebuild. Some changes don't force .o files to update; sorry, I don't have much insight beyond that.

Comment: Its working! You were right just had to delete the .o files. Thanks again